# Track changes not working in Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio, ide, settings

Hey so I have track changes enabled but it still doesn't show. I tried resetting the back to default settings and uninstalling and its not working for me. I have the latest version of the IDE.[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Bogdan I'm listing some of the possible solution for your issue, consider trying it & update me if it works.

1. Sometimes "Track changes" may be disabled even if it's turned on, so try toggling it on and off then Restart your PC after Enabling "Track changes" as some settings need restart to come into effect.
2. Check for any installed IDE Extensions/add-ins related to tracking changes & disable them, as it can affect the behaviour of the IDE.
3. Also Try disabling any third-party softwares temporarily if you're using any. Check for any file permission which it required and provide necessary access.
4. Make sure that the system, IDE, Visual Studio Community, etc... are updated to the latest version.
5. Try uninstall both the softwares and try reinstall them, I think it should work as it will keep all the default settings.

If none of the steps above works consider reaching out to Visual Studio support team regarding the "Track changes" issue

Here is the Link for it : https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/onboarding?origin=/supportforbusiness/create

I hope your issue will be resolved by following with the steps itself. Comment below if it does works. Have a great Day :)